# Get net vat values the vat value in C#

Tags: c#

I need to get the net values (vat @20%) of wallet and paper as below, added together

```
        {
this.transaction.netValue = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(wallet) + Convert.ToDecimal(paper), 2);
        }
```

and then to get the vat value (20%) having established the net values of both wallet and paper

```
      {
    transaction.vatAmount = Round(Convert.ToDecimal(wallet) + Convert.ToDecimal(paper), 2);
      }
```

I know how to do the formulas in excel, but having difficulty in c#

Updated

```
this.transaction.netValue = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal([wallet]/1.2m) + Convert.ToDecimal([paper]/1.2m), 2);
```

Comment: .. (Convert.ToDecimal(wallet)/1.2) with and without square brackets around wallet, results in squiggly lines.

Comment: Use `1.2m` instead of `1.2`

Comment: tried 1.2m, still with squiggly lines

Comment: Update your question with that line of code that makes the problem.

Comment: remove square brackets

Comment: I tested with and without square brackets and tested with an additional set of opening and closing brackets

Comment: Remove the square brackets, place your cursor over the squiggly lines and read what it tells you!

Comment: Operator "/" cannot be applied to operands of type string and decimal

Comment: what is wallet and paper actually?

Comment: wallets are envelopes and paper are another type of envelope

Comment: what are envelops?, I am interested to know the type of variables, can you post little more code for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to decimal first then divide by 1.2m

Comment: Is it not already converted to decimal a per  Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(wallet)  ?

Comment: in your line divides by 1.2M first then converts to decimal

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values in wallet and paper strings are actually valid decimal numbers then you need to apply

```
   decimal totalValue = Convert.ToDecimal(wallet) + 
                        Convert.ToDecimal(paper);
   decimal netValue = totalValue / 1.2m;
   this.transaction.netValue = Math.Round(netValue, 2);
```

Do not put square brackets around the string and do not put the division inside the parameter (a string is required) that you pass to `Convert.ToDecimal`

Of course this could be written in a single line but because you are recalculating again that `netValue` for `vatAmount` then using a temporary variable is better because you can reuse it for the subsequent calculation
(By the way `vatAmount = totalValue - netValue`, right? )

Instead if your inputs are not guaranteed to be correct decimal values then you should use decimal.TryParse

```
   decimal walletValue;
   decimal paperValue;
   if(!decimal.TryParse(wallet, out walletValue))
   {
        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid decimal value for wallet");
        return;
   }
   if(!decimal.TryParse(paper, out paperValue))
   {
        MessageBox.Show("Not a valid decimal value for paper");
        return;
   }
   decimal totalValue = walletValue + paperValue;
   decimal netValue = totalValue / 1.2m;
   this.transaction.netValue = Math.Round(netValue, 2);
   this.transaction.vatValue = Math.Round(totalValue - vatValue, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing squiggly lines because your are trying to divide two different types of datatypes. first your're converting wallet to decimal and then you're dividing it with 1.2 which is double and you need to change it to decimal as well. From [decimal (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx)

> If you want a numeric real literal to be treated as decimal, use the
>   suffix m or M. Without the suffix m, the number is treated as a double
>   and generates a compiler error.

So your final code will be something as follows

```
this.transaction.netValue = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(wallet) / 1.2m + Convert.ToDecimal(paper) / 1.2m, 2);
```

Comment: squiggly lines have gone so will test the results. To get the vat value on those net amounts, should I put the formula at  the end of the line ?

Comment: You need another statement for that, what's the formula, multiplying `netvalue` with 20%?